# 二値分類問題をディープラーニングで解く際にうまく学習されない

Tags: python, 機械学習, numpy, 深層学習

入力されたxとyの値から0か1かを分類できるようにニューラルネットワークを学習させようとしているのですが、何度回してもうまく学習できません。
どうすればよいのか教えていただけると幸いです。

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)) 

def sigmoid_grad(x):
    return (1.0 - sigmoid(x)) * sigmoid(x)

def softmax(x):
    x = x - np.max(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)   # オーバーフロー対策
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=-1, keepdims=True)

def cross_entropy_error(y, t):
    if y.ndim == 1:
        t = t.reshape(1, t.size)
        y = y.reshape(1, y.size)
        
    # 教師データがone-hot-vectorの場合、正解ラベルのインデックスに変換
    if t.size == y.size:
        t = t.argmax(axis=1)
             
    batch_size = y.shape[0]
    return -np.sum(np.log(y[np.arange(batch_size), t] + 1e-7)) / batch_size

#予測を行う関数
def predict(x,params):
        W1, W2 = params['W1'], params['W2']
        b1, b2 = params['b1'], params['b2']
    
        a1 = np.dot(x, W1) + b1
        z1 = sigmoid(a1)
        a2 = np.dot(z1, W2) + b2
        y = softmax(a2)
        return y

#損失関数の計算
# x:入力データ, t:教師データ
def loss(x,t,params):
    y = predict(x,params)
        
    return cross_entropy_error(y, t)

#予測の精度を求める関数
def accuracy(x,t,params):
        y = predict(x,params)
        y = np.argmax(y, axis=1)
        t = np.argmax(t, axis=1)
        
        accuracy = np.sum(y == t) / float(x.shape[0])
        return accuracy

#勾配を求める関数
def gradient(x,t,params):
        W1, W2 = params['W1'], params['W2']
        b1, b2 = params['b1'], params['b2']
        grads = {}
        
        batch_num = x.shape[0]
        
        # forward
        a1 = np.dot(x, W1) + b1
        z1 = sigmoid(a1)
        a2 = np.dot(z1, W2) + b2
        y = softmax(a2)
        
        batch_num = x.shape[0]

        # backward
        dy = (y - t)/batch_num
        grads['W2'] = np.dot(z1.T, dy)
        grads['b2'] = np.sum(dy, axis=0)
        
        dz1 = np.dot(dy, W2.T)
        da1 = sigmoid_grad(a1) * dz1
        grads['W1'] = np.dot(x.T, da1)
        grads['b1'] = np.sum(da1, axis=0)

        return grads


#重みとバイアスの初期化
input_size=2 #入力層
hidden_size=3 #中間層
output_size=2 #出力層

weight_init_std=0.1
params = {}
params['W1'] = weight_init_std * np.random.randn(input_size, hidden_size)
params['b1'] = weight_init_std * np.random.randn(hidden_size)
params['W2'] = weight_init_std * np.random.randn(hidden_size, output_size)
params['b2'] = weight_init_std * np.random.randn(output_size)

#データを分割
f = open('2class.txt', 'r')
datalist = f.readlines()

num=1000
learning_rate=0.01
batch=100
for i in range(num):
    #データ分割
    x=np.array([])
    t=np.array([])
    train_batch_mask = np.random.choice(2000, batch)
    for i in train_batch_mask:
        data=datalist[i].replace( '\n' , '' ).split(' ')
        x=np.append(x,[data[0],data[1]])
        t=np.append(t,[data[2],1-int(data[2])])

    x_test=x.reshape(batch,2).astype(float)
    t_test=t.reshape(batch,2).astype(float)
    
    grad=gradient(x_test,t_test,params)
    # 更新
    for key in ('W1', 'b1', 'W2', 'b2'):
        params[key] -= learning_rate * grad[key]
    inter=num*0.1
    if i % inter ==0:
        print(accuracy(x_test,t_test,params))

f.close()
```

2class.txt
こちらは例でデータ数は2000個あります。

```
0.07998 0.00000 0
0.16921 0.00213 0
0.07037 0.00177 0
0.04757 0.00179 0
0.12735 0.00641 0
-0.14647 -0.14105 1
-0.14371 -0.14192 1
-0.13122 -0.13287 1
-0.12394 -0.12870 1
-0.11359 -0.12096 1
-0.13076 -0.14280 1
-0.13758 -0.15410 1
```

結果

```
0.51
0.53
0.62
0.52
0.58
0.53
0.52
0.47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純にループ回数が不足してるんじゃないかと思います。
2class.txt の内容にもよりますが `x + y > 0` のような単純なケースでも `num=10000` くらい必要で、 `x * y > 0` だと `num=100000` くらい必要でした。

データ処理部分がPythonでのループになってて遅いので

```python
with open('2class.txt', 'r') as f:
    datalist = [list(map(float, l.split(' '))) for l in  f.readlines()]
    datalist = np.array(datalist)
```

で予め配列にしておいて、次のようにnumpy操作だけにすると速くなります。

```python
    train_batch_mask = np.random.choice(2000, batch)
    data = datalist[train_batch_mask]
    x_test = data[:,0:2]
    t = data[:,2]
    t_test = np.stack([t, 1-t], 1)
```

Comment: 気づかず申し訳ございません。ループ回数を増やすのと中間層を10にしたら学習できましたありがとうございました！！！

Answer (score 0):

結果を見るに、うまくできているのではないでしょうか？
2値分類ｔの問題では、結果は0～1の間で出力されるのが普通で、0.5未満なら0、0.5以上なら1と判断します。。0～1の間になるのは、予測器の確度を表すためです。
以下のようなコードで質問に貼られている結果を、0.5未満なら0、0.5以上なら1に置き換えてください。

```
y_pred = np.where(y_pred_prob < 0.5, 0, 1)
```

上手くできていない の意味を捉え違っていたらごめんなさい

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。y = np.argmax(y, axis=1)の部分で出力を置き換えているのでそこではないと思われます。また修正しましたが結果は変わっていませんでした。おそらくほかの部分に原因があると考えられます。ほかに気になる点などございましたらアドバイスいただきたいです。